# Writing my own fulltext

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

I've been playing around with the idea of fulltext for some time now and in spite of all the reading and experimenting I have done I still feel I have an awful lot to learn about its advantages/disadvantages and general practicalities.

For a lot of things it appears to work fantastically well, however a major snag I have been having lately is when it comes to real peoples names - simply put, it refuses to co-operate when it comes to apostrophes, special characters, accents and the like.
So I bit the bullet and decided to try and write my own trigger function to update the 'search' field I wish to index.

Firstly the issue comes when searhcing for a name like Bjorn, when you could also have a Bjørn or a Björn, then- how about or O'Leary, fulltext splits the word into two pieces. What if somebody types the name without the apostrophe? and so on.

In an attempt to deal with it my current effort is as follows:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION quote_insert() RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
DECLARE
  --Set to lowercase and convert any strange vowels or accents to ascii (no Bjørn's, José's etc)
  myString text := to_ascii(convert_to(lower(NEW."name"),'latin1'),'latin1');
  nwString text := '';
  --Split the words up by their spaces and put them in an array
  myArray  text[] := regexp_split_to_array(myString, E'\\s+');
  nArray   text[];
    --These are counters for the secondary array, and for the apostrophe placement
    n int := 0;
    p int;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN 1..array_upper(myArray,1) LOOP
    --If it has an apostrophe (hopefully only one!) split the words up like so: o'leary -> oleary o leary
    IF position('''' in myArray[i]) > 0 
    THEN
      nArray[n] = '''' || regexp_replace(myArray[i], '''', '') || ''':' || n+1 || ' ';
            n = n+1;
      p = position('''' in myArray[i]);
      nArray[n] = '''' || substring(myArray[i],0,p) || ''':' || n+1 || ' ';
      n = n+1;
      nArray[n] = '''' || substring(myArray[i],p+1,length(myArray[i])) || ''':' || n+1 || ' ';
      n = n+1;
    ELSE
      nArray[n] = '''' || myArray[i] || ''':' || n+1 || ' ';
      n = n+1;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;

  --Sort 'nArray' here..........
  --(not even sure if sorting alphabetically is important...)
  --............................

  --Turn the array back into a string
  FOR i IN 0..array_upper(nArray,1) LOOP
    nwString = nwString || nArray[i];
  END LOOP;
  --Set the search field to whatever string is generated
  NEW."search" = trim(nwString);
  RETURN NEW;
END
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';
```

I nearly forgot, I previously added a very handy custom to_ascii script that I lifted from another site-

```
CREATE FUNCTION to_ascii(bytea, name)
RETURNS text STRICT AS 'to_ascii_encname' LANGUAGE internal;
```

so, my script trigger produces text similar to that of fulltext, the only difference being that I noticed is that it arranges the words alphabetically. I do not know if it is necessary, or if it would be efficient to do so, but if I had to then suggestions on sorting would be welcome.

To compare the results of this script and a fulltext it would read:

```
My query (firing trigger function):
INSERT INTO "table" ("name") VALUES ('Bjørn O''Leary') RETURNING "search";
[search]
'bjorn':1 'oleary':2 'o':3 'leary':4

Using fulltext:
SELECT to_tsvector('Bjørn & O''Leary & OLeary'); --Obviously using o'leary and oleary because of different sorting methods
[to_tsvector]
'bjørn':1 'leari':3 'o':2 'oleari':4
```

As you can see, it does not remove the special ø character, and obviously I needed to insert OLeary to get a similar result.

So, to ask questions: Is it better/necessary/faster to have your words organised alphabetically?

Secondly... I hate to ask this now, but is there already a fulltext method of querying names that follow my critera I am just not aware of?

Lastly, the real headache is that I have names spread across several tables inherited from a single one. I may consider adding an insert/update to this trigger, to update a completely seperate 'search' table. is this pushing it too far?

Answer (score 1):

Very very interesting! I've been writing a blog post on name searching with PostgreSQL to try to solve some of the problems involved in name searching.
My half-problem-solving solution, however, may be useful to you. Let's start with the following tricks:

1. If the searcher types at least *two names*, chances are good one of them will be nice (unless they are searching for *Bjørn O'Leary*) and one of them will "match" your full text index. After that, you can use tools such as Levenshtein distance or other string distances and a lot of crafty work to properly order results. This requires you to change your search for an ored search of words, i.e. *Bjørn | O'Leary*, which could result in many more rows being fetched by the database for further processing, so be aware..
2. Not only that, but you can solve the *Bjørn* case for good: use the `unaccent` filtering dictionary! It will "transform" it into "Bjorn", and still solve a lot of other common name mispellings by removing accents! This is part of what your trigger is trying to fix.
3. If this is not enough for you, you can certainly use a *synonym dictionary* to treat special cases, by inserting a few synonyms for *Schwarzenegger* (like *Schwarznegger* and *Schwarzeneger*) and some preprocessing to treat cases where the parser is your major source of pain, like in *O'Leary* (the preprocessing would for example remove apostrophes from the search string, like your trigger does). I do think the synonym dictionary could quickly become a source of pain to maintain, as well, but even a small one may be of great aid in name searching.

   - Note: If you don't want the synonym dictionary but if you do implement something like what I suggested in **(1)**, if the user searches for "Arnold Schwarznegr" (completely wrong) he will still probably find "Arnold Schwarzenegger" very close to the top of the ranked results, since the Levenshtein distance between "Schwarzenegger" and "Schwarzenegger" is very small and Arnold is a full text match!

Hope it helps even a bit.

EDIT: Some links that may be helpful:
[unaccent filtering dictionary](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/unaccent.html)
[Fuzzystrmatch](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/fuzzystrmatch.html)
[pg_trgm module](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/pgtrgm.html)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, there's some good stuff there. On the first point concerning the entries of two or more names, I have been considering something similar to this. I used to have a `LIKE '%%'` search produce something similar when I was using an ajax web form entry (to suggest the best 5 matches or so) but it wasn't very effective and I was running into the erroneous character matching problem, plus word ordering issues. It's definitely something I will work on once I've solved my original issue. Point 2... damn, and thanks ;) on the 3rd as you said it's complicated, but...

Comment: ^(ran out of characters) I do like the idea of dictionary matching for similar spelling, or sounding words. I think first I need to work on the sorting and how I can join it all... efficiently.

Comment: @Lucas as for efficiency: that is why I still go with a full text search index to do a "gross" filtering of rows, although I do recognize that ORing the searched words will probably return a lot of results from the index scan. If you want to use the LIKE operator, you can try to index the name column with the `pg_trgm` module (if you are using Postgres >= 9.1) and use the LIKE operator or the `<->` distance operator efficiently!

Comment: Continuation: As for sound similarity, there is the `fuzzystrmatch` module with a `soundex` system (only good for english words, though). I also forgot to mention you can always write your own parser, to treat cases like O`Leary. Although I do think there's a bit too much effort involved in doing that, it would probably take name searching to its prime. I edited the answer to provide some cool links that may be helpful.